# How to arrange multiple figures in an array of subplots while keeping all properties?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

Imagine I have function `myPlot` which creates a simple plot and returns figure and axes handle:

```
function [ fig_handle, axes_handle ] = myPlot( myTitle )

x = linspace(-10,10,100);
y = x.^2;

fig_handle = figure;
plot(x,y,'Color','b')
ylim([0,42]); xlim([-42/10,42/10]);
ylabel('y'); xlabel('x');
title(myTitle);
grid on;
axes_handle = gca;

end
```

Now I want to call that function multiple times with different input parameters and concatenate them into an array of subplots. The solution I came up with is

```
[f1,a1] = myPlot('Plot #1');
[f2,a2] = myPlot('Plot #2');

figure(3)
s221 = subplot(211);
s222 = subplot(212);
copyobj(get(a1,'children'),s221)
copyobj(get(a2,'children'),s222)
```

it gives me

[image]

so the new 2-part plot does not keep any property of the two plots before. Of course I am aware that I can just do:

```
set(s221,'Ylabel',get(a1,'Ylabel'))
```

with all properties. But I try to avoid this. Is there something easier I am missing?

Comment: My first thought was to do the `set(handle2,get(handle1))` approach you mentioned. Why are you trying to avoid that one? Your other proposed solution will certainly work as well, although I understand that that is not an ideal solution

Comment: @Trogdor there are two labels and two limit properties, the title, box and grid properties. If you then have more than 5 subplots, there are quite some lines of code. Which doesn't really seem necessary, because everything was defined before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another workaround is to copy the full axes object (so all the properties come along) into a new figure. The only property you have left to set yourself is the position according to the rules of subplot(xyz).

To start with your example :

```
[f1,a1] = myPlot('Plot #1');
[f2,a2] = myPlot('Plot #2');
```

Then copy the axis of each figure into the new figure

```
h4 = figure(4)
copyobj(get(f1,'children'),h4)
copyobj(get(f2,'children'),h4)
```

They are both here, but they are still superimposed. You just have to reposition them now.

---

For a quick workaround I use an intermediate figure to let `subplot` calculate the position for me but these positions (axes arrangement) could probably be calculated by yourself with a helper function (rip some code from `subplot.m` if you need).

```
%// Just to get some position calculated for me
figure(3)
s221 = subplot(211);
s222 = subplot(212);
```

---

Then I apply the positions to axes in the figure:

```
hl = flipud( get(h4,'Children') ) ;
set( hl(1),'Position', get(s221,'Position') )
set( hl(2),'Position', get(s222,'Position') )
```

[image: The result:]

Just be careful, the axes/children list is upside down (so the use of the `flipud` function), but if you put that in a loop, you could just run the loop backward.

---

### Edit

If you are going to discard the original figure (`f1` and `f2`), then you can also simply move the axes to the new figure (instead of copying them) by assigning the `Parent` property of the `axes`, then close the figure (to keep things tidy). Just use :

```
set(a1,'Parent',h4) ; close(f1)
set(a2,'Parent',h4) ; close(f2)
```

instead of the 2 lines with `copyobj`. The rest of the solution is identical. Not sure if there is a performance gain by moving an object instead of replicating it (*Matlab may do a copy in the background anyway ... or not*) but if it involve many figures with heavy data sets it may at least save some memory during the process.

Comment: Quite nice, lets see how it works for the real case!

Comment: @thewaywewalk. Glad it works. I just remembered something I used in the past and edited the answer. It may be more efficient depending what you want to do with your intermediate figures.

Answer (score 1):

One possible workaround could be the following, not really generic though. Would be interested in a solution solving the original problem.

If it is possible to modify the `myPlot` function one could pass the figure handle and subplot specifier and plot everything correctly from the beginning.

```
function [ fig_handle, axes_handle ] = myPlot(fig_handle, sub, myTitle )

figure(fig_handle); subplot(sub)

....

end
```

called by

```
f = figure(3);
[f,a1] = myPlot(f, 221,'Plot #1');
[f,a2] = myPlot(f, 222,'Plot #2');
```